# View list on another form

Tags: c#, forms, list

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?
I've got a list in a database class that I want to view in a listbox on my form yet it's not showing anything. 
I call the form from a button click of my first form which is where I enter the data and it works if I put a listbox on that form, but I'm wanting to open another form which will only show the data if that makes sense? 
here's my code for the form that I want to view what's in the list:

```
public partial class Summary : Form
{
    public Summary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private Database viewlist = new Database();

    private void Summary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void sum()
    {
        List<String> listofPicks = viewlist.listPickups();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(listofPicks.ToArray());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sum();
    }

}
```

Also may i make it clear that this code works if it's all done on the same form

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: Yeah I realise it's confusing. Basically, if I try to view my list from the database class in a separate form. It doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (kind of), load the list when the form loads, not on a button click:

```
public partial class Summary : Form
{
    private Database _viewlist = new Database();

    public Summary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Summary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadList();
    }

    private void LoadList()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(_viewlist.Pickups.ToArray());
    }
}

public class Database
{
    public List<string> Pickups
    {
        get { return new List<string> {"alfa", "beta"}; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Database.listPickups()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context"  I receive this error :(

Comment: It's definitely storing the data and everything because it works if I do it on the first form. I just want to view it on form 2

Comment: change viewlist.listPickups.ToArray() to viewlist.listPickups().ToArray()

Comment: ^ that doesn't return an error but it still doesn't show in the list box

Comment: Added full code, it shows alfa & beta in my list when the form is loaded. Of course, you must also hook up the Summary_Load method to the Load event of the form.

Comment: Thanks! it returns no errors but still doesn't show anything. :S

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the call to LoadList (in Summary_Load), do you hit it?